# Accessing files with generated names

Tags: python, bash, file

I am trying to access a file with a name of the following format:

```
TextA.YYYYMMDDhhmmss.TextB.RandomNumber.txt
```

I know what `TextA`, `TextB`, and `YYYYMMDD` value should be. But `hhmmss` and `RandomNumber` are generated on the fly when `UNIX` creates the file.

I have accessed the file in `bash` using the following code

```
#!/bin/bash
timeB=$(date +%Y%m)
MyDate=$(date +%d)
MyDate=$((sysD-1))
file=($HOME/my/path/TextA$timeB$MyDate*)
echo file
```

Result displays the correct file name which is

```
TextA.20130627140221.TextB.23884.txt
```

I am trying to do the same in python now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
import os
os.environ["TOP"]
timeA = time.strftime("%Y%m%d", gmtime)
print "timeA", timeA
file = "%s/my/path/TextA%s*"%(os.environ["TOP"], timeA)
print "file", file
```

The result for file print just displays

```
/Complete/my/path/TextA.20130628*
```

Can you please advise the correct approach to look for the file?

Comment: So what didn't work when you tried `glob`?

Comment: @icedwater It works now. Hadn't implemented my logic properly initially.

Comment: Good to know, but my comment was more directed at the lack of information in your edit. Maybe you could share your answer with us here? --- OK, wrote this before I saw your edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) library.

Answer (score 1):

Implemented as suggested by Amber

Added following to my code

```
fileA = glob.glob(file)
print "fileA >", fileA
```

**Output**

```
fileA > ['/Complete/my/path/TextA.20130627140221.TextB.23884.txt']
```